pageTransition after route change DOM not Updated - Nuxt 3
I have a component that I put in the layout. The component calculates the size of the layout and does something simple:
components/info.vue :
<script lang="ts" setup>
const info = ref() as Ref<HTMLDivElement>;
const content = inject("content") as Ref<HTMLDivElement>;

const route = useRoute();
const setFixed = ref(false);

const scann = () => {
  const elementHegiht = content.value?.clientHeight + content.value?.offsetTop;
  const heightLimit = (window.innerHeight / 100) * 60;

  if (elementHegiht < heightLimit) {
    setFixed.value = true;
  } else {
    setFixed.value = false;
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  scann();
});


watch(route, () => {
  scann();
});


</script>

<template>
  <div ref="info" class="info" :class="{ fixed: setFixed }">
   ...
  </div>
</template>

layouts/default.vue :
<script setup lang="ts">
const content = ref();
provide("content", content);

</script>

<template>
  <div class="default-layout layout">
    <div ref="content" class="content">
      <slot />
      <Info /> 
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


nuxt.config.ts :
...
  app: {
    layoutTransition: {
      name: "layout-trans",
      mode: "out-in",
      appear: true,
    },

    pageTransition: {
      name: "page-trans",
      mode: "out-in",
      appear: true,
    },
}
...

When I move from page 1 to page 2, the value of the elementHegiht variable is the size of the content of the previous page, and I don't want that. I understand that there is an animation in the transition, but is there a specific way after that the DOM is updated directly without delay? I don't want to use setTimeout.
It was working fine before pageTransition but I want to use it.
